# busy hour glass does not appears after I click something

Tags: settings

On my other raspberry pi, when I click something in my GUI a busy hour glass pops up and disappears after the request has granted. Well, this new raspberry pi 4b does not have the hour glass appear. What setting do I have to change to get it to work? thanks

Comment: maybe it's not busy

Comment: not a Raspberry Pi question ... please research in the Linux realm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.